# gulp-pipemin error: Path not found

Tags: gulp

We're getting some generic gulp-pipemin errors which refer to a path not found, but we cannot tell exactly which file path it points to.

We ended up discovering the offending file path, however I would like to know the best way to trap this exception and output some useful information when building the website.

The `pipemin` cmd prompt error is :

```
[13:59:50] Starting 'pipemin'...
Potentially unhandled rejection [1] Error: Path [object Object] not found!
at getFiles (c:\test\MyUiProject\node_modules\gulp-pipemin\index.js:172:17)
```

and the gulp tasks looks something like:

```js
gulp.task('pipemin', function () {
   return gulp.src(['./myFile.html','./myOtherFile.html'])
      .pipe(pipemin({
         css: function(strm, b){
            return strm.pipe(...)
         },
         html: function(strm, b){
            return strm.pipe(...)
         },
         js: function(strm, b){
            return strm.pipe(...)
         },
      }))
});
```

Is there a way to properly handle this exception, and output some useful information for tracking down the missing path ?

Thank you in advance...